# From one Controller to another?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a ShopController and an Action method that I call CheckOut. I have [Authorize] before the the Action method, but what if I want the user to continue , after a successfull log in, to another Controller like the CustomersController and the Create View so that the customer can add address and other info into a form?

One option would could be to create a new View with a form within the ShopController, but I guess that isn't a good option!?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Do you want to redirect from the `ShopController` to the `CustomerController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One option would could be to create a new View with a form within the
>   ShopController, but I guess that isn't a good option!?

No. This is the way you want to do it. Create action methods/controllers for different functional/logical pieces of your application. In this case, reading the address is a separate functionality and hence should belong to a separate controller-action method.

You may create a new `CustomerController` and add a `CreateAddress` action method ( and view) in that and in your action method which authenticates the user(Login?), use `RedirectToAction` method to send the user your new view as needed.

```
public ActionResult Login(string userName,string password)
{
  // do your credential verification logic here
  return RedirectToAction("CreateAddress","CustomerController");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!